# Is it possible to host Node JS applications to IPFS? Possibly through Fleek?

Tags: node.js, hosting, continuous-deployment, ipfs, decentralized-applications

Is it possible to host Node JS applications to IPFS? Possibly through Fleek? I know it's possible to host React JS app on IPFSA Using Fleek, but is it possible to host or run a Node server on IPFS, or is there any other decentralized way to host a Node JS app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fleek uses IPFS which only includes files and not a processing engine like Node. You can run a React App if the build process exports to a static site. You cannot host a NodeJS app because it requires the node engine to run in order to execute your code.

Think about IPFS a bit like a distributed Vercel or Netlify without the possibility to run serverless functions. Or like a distributed CDN.

In short, IPFS in general or via Fleek, can be used only for files / static website. React, Vue, Svelte can still be used but only as a client side solution so if you export a static website.